# Can ThingsBoard read the OTA partition offsets and deploy an app update to a particular OTA partition?

Tags: esp32, thingsboard

I've been presented with a task where the requirements are that the ThingsBoard should read the OTA partitions of the ESP-32 and deploy an update to a particular partition. Can someone tell me if it's possible?

I've tried looking into the documentation but there was no mention of it. I might have missed some part, that's why i'm asking the community.